# detection browser type and version using javascript

Tags: browser

function getBrowserInfo()
{
var ua=  navigator.userAgent;
M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=/))/?\s*([\d.]+)/i) || [];
if(/trident/i.test(M[1]))
{
    tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
}
M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
if((tem= ua.match(/version/([.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    return M.join(' ');
}
alert(getBrowserInfo());

Answer (score 0):

BROWSER TYPE

```
var browserType = navigator.appName;
alert('Browser type is: ' + browserType);
```

BROWSER VERSION

```
var browserVersion = navigator.appVersion;
alert('Browser version is: ' + browserVersion);
```